# Eigenvalues - Covariance Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let X be a mean-zero random vector in $R^d$ (so
E(X) = 0). Let  $\sum_ := E(XX^T)$ be the covariance matrix of X, and suppose its eigenvalues are $\lambda_1$ >=$\lambda_2$ >=... >=$\lambda_n$ > 0. Let $\sigma^2$ > 0 be a positive number.

(a) What are the eigenvalues of  $\sum + \sigma^2I$?

(b) What are the eigenvalues of ($\sum + \sigma^2I)^{-1}$?

(c) Suppose R $\epsilon R^{d x d}$ is an invertible symmetric matrix that satises RR =  $\sum + \sigma^2I$? Let $v_1 \epsilon R^d$ be an eigenvector of  $\sum$ corresponding to its largest eigenvalue $\lambda_1$. What is the
variance of the random variable $v{^T}_1 R^{-1}X$ ? (The answers can be given in terms of $\sigma ^ 2$ and the eigenvalues of $\lambda$.)

Comment: Hint: since $\Sigma$ is symmetric, it is diagonalizable by an orthormal basis: $\Sigma = A D A^\top$, where $A$ is orthogonal, and $D=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$. From this can you get a diagonalization of $\Sigma + \sigma^2 I$?